# Magento 2 : How to add URL rewrite to static HTML file

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, seo, landing-pages

I have a static HTML content that is used as a promotional landing page for our website, so it doesn't need to have Magento headers, footers, etc. Just a static landing page.

I put the whole landing page folder `mylandingpage/` into `pub/` folder and can access it by going to `www.mysite.com/mylandingpage/index.html`

However i want to modify the URL to make it more SEO friendly, so i went to `Marketing/SEO & Search/URL Rewrites` and create a new custom URL Rewrite with `'Request Path'` as `'newlanding'` and `'Target Path'` is `'mylandingpage/index.html'`. But `www.mysite.com/newlanding` is throwing 404.

Am i missing anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're writing content in an html file, outside the scope of magento so I think magento router controller/ url rewrite would not work on it.

You can rewrite the url using your `.htaccess` file, just add following code your `.htaccess` located on magento's root ;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^mylandingpage\/index\.html$ /newlanding/ [R=301,L]
```

It should rewrite `www.mysite.com/mylandingpage/index.html` to `www.mysite.com/newlanding/`

Comment: We will have a lot more landing pages in the future and these landing pages could come from 3rd party outsourcing companies that will have their own stylesheets and javascript files so i was trying to isolate them into a specific folder and manage their SEO links through Magento, but that sounds like i can't do that then. Thanks for your answer, it might be the only solution.

Comment: You can always use server side rewrite in htaccess.
Please mark the answer as accepted  if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

1. First you haven't to add your files in `/pub` folder because it is a generated one.
2. Simply to add your content file after base url `www.mysite.com/newlanding`, you just have to create a cms page `Admin > Content cms page` you put a name as `newlanding` you save, then call it in your url as your exemple then you will have you landing page.